# configure python and cvblob

Tags: python, ubuntu

Hi I'm trying to configure cvblob in order to use it with python ,using the explanition h here but when i came to test it i got this error:

```
sabrine@sabrine-Aspire-5742Z:~/Downloads/cvblob/python/cvblob$ ./build.sh
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
         from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:8,
         from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
         from _cvblob.C:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No  such file or directory
# include <pyconfig.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
g++: error: _cvblob.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by following the steps in the git hub website
without ignoring the small notes between brackets :p